# Constructing a Borel set A on R such that $0<m(A \cap I) < m(I)$ for all intervals $I$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I need help constructing a Borel set $A$ on $\mathbb{R}$ with the following property:

For every open interval $I$,

$$0<m(A \cap I)< m(I)$$

A obviously needs to be dense in $\mathbb{R}$ and it also must have empty interior, but honestly I don't know what to do from here on.

Even the generalized cantor set doesn't have positive measure for all the sub intervals it is constructed on.....

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ is a Baire Space and $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable